# htaccess rules to skip files and directory but checking by matching with a prefix first

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using following rules which skips files if paths to them is already provided.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But this makes me, to access the files like `site.com/public/js/somefile.js`, which is not intented.

Can we check if file exists inside a directory and rewrite the url so to access it as `site.com/js/somfile.js"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -"public/"f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Obvioulsy this didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: The first rule (which passes through with a `-`) is supposed to match files that exists. So assuming `site.com/js/somfile.js` exists, it should match the first rule and pass through without being rewritten.

Comment: @JonLin file exists inside `public` directory which should be accesible without the public

Comment: @mrN: Has your problem been resolved?

Comment: @anubhava, No it is not could you help me out?

Comment: So actual file is `site.com/js/somfile.js` instead of `site.com/public/js/somefile.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Right before this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It gets redirected to `site.com/public/js`

Comment: Also, every request has a `public/` infront

Comment: @mrN There's nothing here that does any redirecting, something else is doing that

Comment: There is not other htaccess file other than this. There is no redirection code in my code.